# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS screen freezing frequently

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, freeze

I'm brand new to Linux and am having a very hard time troubleshooting this problem. My screen is freezing frequently .

Here is my machine specs:

```
Intel Core 2 duo E8400 3Ghz,
5Gb RAM,
Ubuntu 14.04 x64
Intel Graphics
```

[Output of `sudo lshw -c video`](http://pastebin.com/AsXESsLf) as requested by Fabby

Comment: Only the screen?  Or the entire computer? (After tapping the off-switch on your computer for <2 seconds, does it still switch off within a few minutes?)

Comment: the whole system is freezing, even when i want to change displays it said a unknown device, so i think its a problem with graphic device

Comment: Please help us help you: does the computer still shut down when you press the power off switch for less then 2 seconds?

Comment: yes it shuts down

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lshw -c video`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AsXESsLf

Comment: You've got 2 video controllers: can you disable one of them in the BIOS or physically remove it from the machine???

Comment: i have only one, its intel default graphics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps `X server` may choose incorrect driver for your computer.

If the current version of `Xorg` that you use supports your computer, you need to try manually change the driver via a file, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf`.
This file describes  `Xorg` server configurations.

Please create the `xorg.conf` file with following contents.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Configured Video Device"
    Driver "vesa"
EndSection
```

And then you can reboot so check your screen again.

If it's failed, you can modify `"vesa"` to `"fbdev"` or `"intel"` at `xorg.conf` and then retry.

Why do I recommend `vesa`, `fbdev`, `intel`? Because they are compatible drivers for the Intel graphics card.

In other case, `X` driver may be updated.
So you may need to run

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

And then reboot again.
Also, you can check that your PC is certificated by Ubuntu Desktop with following url.
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/
At there, you can lookup for your PC.

Note:

If you use `vesa` and `fbdev`, direct dendering may be disabled.

If you still cannot solve your problem, please visit

https://launchpad.net/xorg

and report this problem as a bug. `Xorg` developers will offer more technical support.

As normally, the X run on tty7. If X crashed or could not reply with black screen, you can switch to the tty1~6 with Ctrl + Alt + 1~6.
And there are many text editors in Ubuntu like `nano`, `vim` and so on.

Also there are some solutions that may help you due to visit following urls.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=935756
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze