# Xbuntu 18.04 is randomly freezing

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, 18.04, amd-graphics

My system is randomly freezing for 2 to 3 seconds. Keyboard, display , mouse cursor even audio stop responding in those time ! Although there is no problem when I use windows. Recently I upgraded the system from 16.04 to 18.04, but still the problem persists. I think the graphics driver is the main culprit, although I am not sure. I am using Dell Inspiron N5442 , cpu : 4th Generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4005U , gpu: AMD Radeon(TM) HD R5 M240 2GB DDR3 , ram: 4 Giga . I didn't install any additional driver.

Here is the output of `lshw -c video`

```
 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Jet XT [Radeon R5 M240]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:c0500000-c053ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0540000-c055ffff
```

I already tried some solution from previous posts ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835111/ubuntu-16-04-seemingly-random-freezing-on-amd-system) [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945895/solution-to-intel-graphics-screen-tearing-flickering-causes-excessive-fan-use) [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696681/ubuntu-14-04-lts-screen-freezing-frequently) [4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360709/how-to-blacklist-amdgpu)) , but none them are fixing my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.dpm=0 radeon.aspm=0 radeon.bapm=0 radeon.runpm=0"`   in  `/etc/default/grub`